# How do i set DB parameters separately for different databases in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, parameters, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to set different values for same parameter in two different databases in Postgres,using below command.

```
alter system set work_mem = "100MB"; #DB1
alter system set work_mem = "20MB"; #DB2
```

However value set for the second databases is showing for both DB's after updating.

Please guide me how to set parameters at databases level.

Postgres Version: 9.6
Environment: testing

Comment: `alter databse sb1 set work_mem`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html

> ALTER DATABASE name SET configuration_parameter { TO | = } { value |
>   DEFAULT }

and example:

```
t=# alter database t set work_mem to '1MB';
ALTER DATABASE
t=# alter database o set work_mem to '2MB';
ALTER DATABASE
t=# \c o
You are now connected to database "o" as user "postgres".
o=# show work_mem ;
 work_mem
----------
 2MB
(1 row)

o=# \c t
You are now connected to database "t" as user "postgres".
t=# show work_mem ;
 work_mem
----------
 1MB
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi,
Getting error when trying to update parameter using above command,
ROCPSREF=# ALTER DATABASE ROCPSREF SET WORK_MEM = "100MB";
ERROR:  database "rocpsref" does not exist

Comment: well, it means that `ROCPSREF` database does not exist. do you confuse schema with database?..

Comment: Yes,looks like that.
Thank you for your quick responses!